# Configure default data source for Arquillain Test in OpenLiberty

Tags: jdbc, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian, open-liberty

I started a new [ejb branch](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter-boilerplate/tree/ejb) to add some simple Ejb and JPA codes.

Java EE 6/7 should include a default data source via `java:comp/DefaultDataSource`, but it is not available in OpenLiberty by default.

I added the following config to *server.xml* to provide a `DefaultDataSource`.

```xml
    <!-- Derby Library Configuration -->
    <library id="derbyJDBCLib">
        <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}" includes="derby*.jar"/>
    </library>

    <!-- Datasource Configuration -->
    <!-- remove jndiName="" to serve java:comp/DefaultDataSource for Java EE 7 or above -->
    <dataSource id="DefaultDataSource">
        <jdbcDriver libraryRef="derbyJDBCLib" />
        <properties.derby.embedded databaseName="ExampleDb" createDatabase="create"/>
    </dataSource>
```

The derby lib is prepared by Maven dependency plugin, see [here](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter-boilerplate/blob/ejb/pom.xml#L1086).

When running the codes, I got a deployment Timeout exception.

Check the details [here](https://github.com/hantsy/jakartaee8-starter-boilerplate/pull/111/checks?check_run_id=1844936129#step:5:9162).

**Update**: resolved via issue [OpenLiberty/liberty-arquillian#94](https://github.com/OpenLiberty/liberty-arquillian/issues/94).

Add an *appDeployTimeout* into *arquillian.xml*.

```xml
<property name="appDeployTimeout">120</property>
```

Comment: Liberty does include a DefaultDataSource as part of JavaEE, but you must complete the configuration of the datasource since Liberty doesn't ship with a bundled database.  Your dataSource definition looks correct. But, you probably need to resolve this error in the output from your test:
8823 FINER: AppMBean for test is in state STARTING
8824 [ERROR   ] CWWKZ0013E: It is not possible to start two applications called test.

Comment: @FRowe Thanks, I have tried to resolve this issue via [IBM docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/websphere-application-server-liberty-profile-applications-security-configuration-serverxml-file-must-not-be-deployed-dropins-folder), but it did not work.

Comment: I used a similar config in before applications, it worked, but not sure the reason that it did not work in the tests.